# Magento catlog price rules are inactive but products are still on sale

Tags: php, magento

We have magento store and we have deleted some catalog price rules by mistake instead of make them inactive. But now we make all Catalog Price Rules inactive. We can see some of our products are still displaying on sale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you have deleted the active rules but rules applied to that product is still active

create a list of product which is still on sale and run below query to find out those rules

```
select * from catalogrule_product group by rule_id where product_id = your product id
```

once you got the rule id of rules then run below query for active deleted rules

```
select * from catalogrule_product group by rule_id;
```

then you got a list of all rule_ids and compare with rules currently existed then you will be able to found those deleted rules

I suggest you to update the id's those rules manually and then do what ever you want to do that